# Doctrine DBAL query buider joins and where clause

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

To generate a report I (i.e. that has 0 whenever a value is nonexistent for a certain date) I use a calendar table.

The problem is that any extra conditions in my query need to go into the join clause. That makes the otherwise so flexible QB very unflexible.

```
$this->query->select('dt AS date, count o.orderId) as orders');
$this->query->from('calendar_table', 'ct');
$this->query->leftJoin('ct', 'orders', 'o', 
    'o.orderDate = ct.dt AND o.SOME_EXTRA_CONDITION = VALUE');
$this->query->groupBy('dt');
```

The problem is the o.SOME_EXTRA_CONDITION = VALUE part. Is there any way I can get this condition out of the join clause and in an extra QB call like

```
$this->query->where(o.SOME_EXTRA_CONDITION = VALUE)?
```

Of course putting the condition in a normal where clause does noet yield the same result, as this happens *after* the join on the final result but what I need is a where clause on the right table only *before* the join.

Answer (score 0):

An example for `leftJoin` from the [official doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

```
// Example - $qb->leftJoin('u.Phonenumbers', 'p', Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('p.area_code', 55))
// Example - $qb->leftJoin('u.Phonenumbers', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.area_code = 55')
// Example - $qb->leftJoin('u.Phonenumbers', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.area_code = 55', 'p.id')
public function leftJoin($join, $alias, $conditionType = null, $condition = null, $indexBy = null);
```

Try changing your `leftJoin` accordingly

```
$this->query->leftJoin('ct.orders', 'o', 'WITH','o.orderDate = ct.dt AND o.SOME_EXTRA_CONDITION = VALUE');
```

Comment: I'm using doctrine DBAL http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#join-clauses so my syntax is quite alright.  In any case what I'm lokking for is a way to flexibly add conditions to the right table _before_ the join. With you example also the  o.SOME_EXTRA_CONDITION = VALUE is hardcoded into the join call. But I need to be able to add another condition o.ANOTHER_CONDITION = ANOTHER_VALUE